# Executing many R commands one by one on a running docker container

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

I have a running container with RStudio image and my own preinstalled package. My task is to call different functions from the package one by one - an output from one function is the input to other functions. I don't want to do it this way: `fun1(x) %>% fun2(x) %>% ... %>% funN(x)`. I want it to work like this:

```
out1 <- fun1(x)
out2 <- fun2(out1)
...
funN(outN-1)
```

The reason I'd it like to be done this way is that I'd like to call these functions as separate `docker exec` commands against the running container. I'm planning to convert these commands into separate Jenkins jobs.

I tried `docker exec ...` commands but failed on the second step. In the first step, the `fun1` function creates an R object `out1`. But the `out1` is not available for the second `docker exec` call, i.e. this does not work:

```
docker run --name=my_container -d my_image (ok)
docker exec -it my_container Rscript main.R (ok)
docker exec -it my_container R "-e my_package::fun2(out1)" (not ok - object out1 not found)
```

where `main.R` is something like this:

```
library(my_package)
out1 <- my_package::fun1()
```

In other words, the next `docker exec` is a continuation of the previous one - all the objects living in the R workspace after the previous step is finished should be available for functions in the next step. Is it possible?
I'd like to avoid putting all the functions (steps) into one R script. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You should give a reproducible example!  We do not know which RStuidio image you're using, what your preinstalled package is, what type of functions you are calling etc. If you want people to help you, give please information...

Comment: I use rocker/tidyverse pulled from Docker Hub. The shape of my custom package is irrelevant in this case. It's a set of R functions. I'd like to call different functions with `docker exec -it my_container R "-e my_package::some-function()" `. The problem is one function produces an output which should be an input to another function, and I don't know how to make the output available to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    docker run -it rocker/rstudio-stable:3.5.1 echo 'set.seed(123); 
    out1 <- base::sample(1:100, 3);
    print(out1);
    out2 <- out1 * 3;
    print(out2)'  | R --no-save
```

Output:

```
> set.seed(123);
                 >     out1 <- base::sample(1:100, 3);
                                                      >     print(out1);
                                                                        [1] 29 79 41
                                                                                    >     out2 <- out1 * 3;
                                                                                                           >     print(out2)
                                                                                                                            [1]  87 237 123
                                                                                                                                           >
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly I am searching for. In your example, all R commands are executed at once. Using your code, I'm more interested in something like this: ```docker execute -it my_container R "-e out1 <- base::sample(1:100, 3)"``` and then the second (separate) call ```docker execute -it my_container R "-e out2 <- out1 * 3"```

Comment: You probably can't do that this way, because every `exec` is separate R session which is not persistent and ends after code is executed. You can try workaround and save outputs to RDS, but then you'll have to figure out somehow whether previous process is still in progress or not.